# regex to find a word before a character, after a space, but not if a ',' comes before the space

Tags: regex

ok, im formatting accounts for an ftp...
the accounts are arranged as follows:

```
bob, joe:######
```

however, some account names have middle initials / middle names after them, like this:

```
bob, joe r:######
bob, joe ryan:######
```

i have tried [^, ]*(:+) but it picks up a last name IF there is no middle name / initial (it also picks up the :  )

i need to get ONLY the middle name / initial. thanks!

Comment: Which regex engine? And what exactly is the desired output? It's better to write those things down, rather than on the heading of your question.

Comment: What language, and why do you want to use a regex? Wouldn't splitting on the : make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a negative lookahead, which not all Regex languages support. In perl, your regex would look like this:

```
/(?!,) (.*?)(:.+)/

perl -e 'print "$1 -- $2" if "bob, joe:######" =~ /(?!,) (.*?)(:.+)/;'
joe -- :######

perl -e 'print "$1 -- $2" if "bob, joe r:######" =~ /(?!,) (.*?)(:.+)/;'
joe r -- :######
```

Comment: yea, im not using a programming language for this.... i made a c++ program that formats the list of account:passowrd's into an XML for the ftp client we are using... i could add the regex to the c++ project, but to be honest - i have never used regex in a c++ project, as i usualy do game dev type stuff. im using <http://www.regextester.com/> probably not the best tool... so im open so suggestions on that..  also, id you dont mind, can you explain how exactly the above regex works? i tried using wikipedia and figure it out... but im not too good with regex (obviously) :p

Comment: the regex works by looking first for a space *not* followed by a `,` (`(?!,) `). Once it finds that space, it looks for characters up to the `:`, then gets all the characters after that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand 100% but I would guess you want to find the "r" and "ryan" in the second example. In that case try

```
[^:]*\s+(\w+):[^:]*
```

[^:]*\s+ matches everything before
:[^:]* matches everything after

One problem is it will pick up the lastname if there is no middle not sure if that is a problem

Noticed you dont want the lastname in that case I modified it to require a last name else there is no match:

```
[^:]*,\s+\w+\s+(\w+):[^:]*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  If you're asking to match on the middle name and initial, then you could use the following regex in python: `\w+\s+\w`.

On the following file:

```
tom, smith:######
bob, joe k:######
nick, ryan stevens:######
```

You would get the following output:

```
joe k
ryan s
```

Edit:  since some names have hyphens in them I would use the following regex: `[a-zA-Z\-]+\s+\w`.